# Enable Soap for PHP 5.5.x on CentOS 6.5

Tags: centos, nginx, php, php-fpm, configuration

Unfortunately I have to support soap on my server for the Fedex webservice. I recompiled PHP enabling support and it works via CLI but not PHP-fpm. They both point to the same ini file and both show the module loaded, but only CLI shows the configuration values.

Output of `php -i | grep -i soap`

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/etc
Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/etc/php.ini
Configure Command =>  './configure'  '--prefix=/usr/local' '--with-config-file-path=/usr/local/etc' '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/usr/local/etc/php_user/' '--enable-fpm' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-libxml' '--enable-mbstring' '--enable-pdo' '--enable-soap' '--enable-sockets=shared' '--enable-zip' '--with-curl' '--with-fpm-group=nginx' '--with-fpm-user=nginx' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr/lib64/' '--with-gd' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr/lib64/' '--with-libdir=lib64' '--with-mcrypt' '--with-openssl' '--with-pdo-mysql' '--with-pear' '--with-readline' '--with-tidy' '--with-xsl' '--with-zlib' '--without-pdo-sqlite' '--without-sqlite3'
soap
Soap Client => enabled
Soap Server => enabled
soap.wsdl_cache => 1 => 1
soap.wsdl_cache_dir => /tmp => /tmp
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled => 1 => 1
soap.wsdl_cache_limit => 5 => 5
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl => 86400 => 86400
```

Output from php-fpm phpinfo():

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /usr/local/etc
Loaded Configuration File   /usr/local/etc/php.ini
SOAP    Brad Lafountain, Shane Caraveo, Dmitry Stogov
```

Please help, I have tried so many things...

Comment: Nevermind, I am an idiot... I needed to recopy the php-fpm binary back into /usr/local/bin. Hopefully if someone else has to recompile PHP, this will help them...

Comment: where do you run php-fpm phpinfo() ? in command line or in a php file ?

Comment: Sorry for the super long delay. You can run it from either. Create a file with phpinfo() in it and run it through your web server. Or find your php-fpm binary (I compiled from source so I manually place it in /usr/local/bin) and run php-fpm -i